# how to parse multiple XML elements into one string?

Tags: python, xml, pandas

Consider the following `XML` that contains only two nodes called `Mydoc`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Mydoc Time="2017-01-02"
    Period="2017-01-03">
    <mycontent ClassID="kinder">
        <bibliography>
            <Id>
                <Num>123456</Num>
            </Id>
                <Body>
this is some crazy text my friend
                </Body>
                <myreaders>
                    <names>
                        <Id>john</Id>
                        <value>95</value>
                    </names>
                </myreaders>
                <school>
                    <myclass>
                        <Id>12</Id>
                        <name>Laura</name>
                    </myclass>
                    <myclass>
                        <Id>14</Id>
                        <name>Frank</name>
                    </myclass>
                    <myclass>
                        <Id>144</Id>
                        <name>Jonny</name>
                    </myclass>
                    <myclass>
                        <Id>222</Id>
                        <name>Alex</name>
                    </myclass>
                    <myclass>
                        <Id>5443</Id>
                        <name>Johnny Doe</name>
                    </myclass>
                </school>
        </bibliography>
</mycontent>
    <mycontent ClassID="preK">
        <bibliography>
            <Id>
                <Num>123456</Num>
            </Id>
                <Body>
this is another crazy text my friend
                </Body>
                <myreaders>
                    <names>
                        <Id>fritz</Id>
                        <value>133</value>
                    </names>
                </myreaders>
        </bibliography>
</mycontent>
</Mydoc>
```

I am trying to use `xml.etree` to parse it and to put each node `mydoc` it into a single row in a `Pandas` dataframe.

However, as you can see, there are multiple elements called `myclass` that I would like to combine into one single cell of my dataframe.

For instance, the expected output (a `Pandas` dataframe with *two rows and two columns*) would be something like:

```
myreaders      school
"(john-95)"  "(12-Laura),(14-Frank),(144-Johnny),(222-Alex),(5443-Johnny Doe)"
"(fritz-133)" ""
```

I tried to play with `xpath` but I was unable to combine my `xpath` lookups into a stringified list like `"(12-Laura),(14-Frank),(144-Johnny),(222-Alex),(5443-Johnny Doe)"`

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Post a little bit of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to other answers, bit shorter, works with newly added nodes:

```
parsedXML = ET.parse( "sample.xml")
root = parsedXML.getroot()
pairs0 = []
pairs1 = []
for mycontent in root.iter('mycontent'):
    pairs0.append(','.join(['(' + name[0].text + '-' + name[1].text + ')' for name in mycontent.iter('names')]))
    pairs1.append(','.join(['(' + myclass[0].text + '-' + myclass[1].text + ')' for myclass in mycontent.iter('myclass')]))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"myreaders": pairs0, "school": pairs1}, columns=['myreaders', 'school'])
```

Edit: reworked to address multiple cases.

Comment: strangely enough I get a dataframe with just one row... any ideas?

Comment: I think the issue is that the pairs name - number are not quoted individually here

Comment: hey turo that seems to be working great for most of the fields! some of them return `TypeError: must be str, not NoneType`. Have you ever seen that?

Comment: OK I understand what is going on. Some of the `names` element may have more or less than two childs. Therefore using `name[0] + name[1]` could break the code. Do you know how to iterate over all the `names[i]` in your code? that is, instead of hardcoding `name[0]` + `name[1]` + `name[2]`, etc

Comment: Hi Noobie, I have not come across something like this, it seems like there are some empty nodes or other formatting issues in your XML but that's just guessing...

Comment: Hi Noobie, that would be the same approach as before in my view, just yet another loop on top. I suggest you play with it further.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [XmlToDict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict), and parse your XML to dictionaries/lists, it could make what your trying to do a lot easier.
You could then loop/through what would be a list of myclass dictionaries.
Hope that helps somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

It became quite the list comprehension contraption, but I think this is what you need.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
dicty = {}
dicty['myreaders'] = [','.join(['(' + x.findall('Id')[0].text + '-' + x.findall('value')[0].text + ')' for x in (root.findall('.//mycontent/bibliography/myreaders/names'))])]
dicty['school'] = [','.join(['(' + x.findall('Id')[0].text + '-' + x.findall('name')[0].text + ')' for x in (root.findall('.//mycontent/bibliography/school/myclass'))])]
print(dicty)
print(pd.DataFrame(dicty))
```

Output:

```
   myreaders                                             school
0  (john-95)  (12-Laura),(14-Frank),(144-Jonny),(222-Alex),(...
```

There is no real easy way to parse xml, you need quite a lot of into about the data structure.

Comment: amazing!!! but would this work if one of the nodes was missing the `myreaders` field entirely?!

Comment: Yes, you'll just loop over an empty list then, returning also an empty list (but no errors).

Comment: thanks that is really useful. can I just as a follow up question? assume there are a few nodes like this in the XML. What would be the best way to loop over them using your dictionary? The idea is to end up with a dataframe with as many rows as nodes... thanks!!!!

Comment: it really depends on the naming of your nodes, but since even in this simple example you already have (id - name) and (id - value) combinations, there is not easy way of looping over this stuff. You need to look for the right combinations by hand, or risk not finding the right stuff.

Comment: well each node is a different `mycontent` tag here, so cant we loop over these directly?

Comment: Sure, but you probably have to change the design a bit.

Comment: OK. let me add one more node to the example then. this is more complete example that people will find useful

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: same issue as above. your nice code actually breaks with the modified example. the issue seems to be that the pairs name-numbers are incorrectly quoted during the process.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using the lxml module? It has some pretty convinient methods to parse and traverse an xml file.
For example I tried the following findall-lists and combined them, which you can then add to the "rest" of your record:

```
from lxml import etree
root = etree.parse(path_to_xml_file)
ids = [i.text for i in root.findall(".//myclass/Id")]
names = [n.text for n in root.findall(".//myclass/Name")]
comb = list(zip(ids,names))
```

This would give you:

```
[('12', 'Laura'), ('14', 'Frank'), ('144', 'Jonny'), ('222', 'Alex')]
```

Comment: that is pretty cool but I need them to be stored in a pandas dataframe

Comment: If you search SO for 'list to pandas' you can solve this. Can't ping you as my current browser only supports ASCII text.

Comment: thanks! I have added one node to make the example more relevant

Comment: Instead of searching `root.findall("abc")` you should iterate over the respective elements first then.

Comment: @RonnyMeißner thanks! could you please update your answer then?